# Powershell via VBScript - Environmental Variable path terminated when username contains spaces

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I have been working on a Powershell Winforms app that requires the console window to be hidden. To do this, I am calling a .ps1 script from a .vbs file (as starting via another .ps1 script and using "-WindowStyle Hidden" still briefly shows the console window upon opening the script). I am using the following code:

```
Dim shell,command
command = "powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command ""%localappdata%\test\test.ps1"""
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run command,0
```

This works with no issues when using an account name with no spaces (e.g. "TESTUSER" will resolve to "C:\USERS\TESTUSER\AppData\Local"). However, when any part of the path generated by the "%localappdata%" environmental variable contains spaces (in this case, using something like "TEST USER 1"), Powershell will terminate the command at "C:\Users\TEST" with an error stating: "The term "C:\Users\TEST" is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program."

I am aware that any strings with spaces in VBScript need to use two sets of surrounding double quotes (""path with spaces""), but this doesn't work in this case - I have tried every combination that has been suggested and the %localappdata% path still has the same issue.

**Things I have tried:**

*Two quotes surrounding path (Working with no spaces):*

```
command = "powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command ""%localappdata%\test\test.ps1"""
```

*Two quotes surrounding entire argument:*

```
command = ""powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command ""%localappdata%\test\test.ps1""""
```

*Single quotes surrounding both:*

```
command = "powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command "%localappdata%\test\test.ps1""
```

*Expanding %localappdata% variable:*

```
Dim shell,path,command
Set shell.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
path = shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%localappdata%")
command = "powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command " & path &"\test\test.ps1"
shell.Run command,0
```

*Adding "Chr(34)" to replace spaces:*

```
command = "powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command ""%localappdata%\test\test.ps1""" & Chr(34)
```

*Using:*

> "$env:localappdata" or "$env:username"

*(both inside and out of "command" quotes) to replace*

> "%localappdata%" or "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local"

I have also tried various solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30064463/running-powershell-script-with-spaces-in-path-from-vbs) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016488/hiding-a-powershell-window-using-vbscript-whitespace-in-the-file-filepath), but nothing works in this case.

I also tried replacing %localappdata% with the absolute file path ("C:\Users\TEST USER 1\AppData\Local\test\test.ps1"), but this also gives the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first is the correct approach for VBScript encoded file paths - `command = "powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command ""%localappdata%\test\test.ps1"""`. However, that doesn't mean Powershell will be happy with it and may expect something else. The best test is take VBScript out of the equation and just run `powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command "%localappdata%\test\test.ps1"` from the command prompt, what is the result?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45762288/1682881

Comment: I seem to have found the solution after trying your suggestion - using `"-File"` instead of `"-command"` seems to run the command without issues:

`command = "powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%localappdata%\test\test.ps1"""`

Thanks a lot for the suggestion!

Comment: The [duplicate explains it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45762288/1682881) in enough detail for you to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since **you're invoking a *script file by path*** rather than passing *PowerShell statements* to [PowerShell's CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), **use the `-File` parameter**, not `-Command`, which implicitly solves your quoting problems:

```vb
' Note the use of -File instead of -Command
command = "powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%localappdata%\test\test.ps1"""
```

The reason that `-Command` didn't work in your case is that its argument(s) are subject to *another round of interpretation*, namely as PowerShell code, *after stripping syntactic `"` chars.* during command-line parsing. This means that a path with spaces is then seen *unquoted* by PowerShell, causing the invocation to fail; you'd need additional quoting -either *escaped* `"` quotes (`\"...\"`, i.e. `\""...\""` from inside a VBScript string) or single quotes (`'...'`), which in turn would necessitate use of `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-):

```
' With -Command: note the embedded '...' quoting and the need to call with `&`
' However, there's usually no need for -Command to invoke scripts with arguments.
command = "powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ""& '%localappdata%\test\test.ps1'"""
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67458726/45375) for more information.